# Creating javascript event listeners on unique rows created by php loop

Tags: javascript, php

Forgive me if I word the title wrong, I'm speculating on what my problem might be as I'm not a javascript coding expert. I have a series of divs that are generated by a php loop with unique ids created by adding the unique id contained in an auto increment column in the mysql db table that contains all the info for the row.

When the user clicks on the div this function fires off:

```
onclick=\"showModal('".$rowInfo['ID']."_row-id')\"
```

javascript code:

```
function showModal(ID) { /* code that shows hidden modal window */ }
```

This works fine, however now I need to start adding javascript buttons (in my case img tags with onclick functions) to the div with the showModal onclick function.

I added this code to the showModal(ID) function:

```
var downArrow = document.getElementById(ID+'_down-arrow'); // Down arrow is the button users click to show addition buttons/divs
downArrow.addEventListener('click',arrowCheck,false); // checks to see if down arrow was clicked, if so arrowCheck function runs and stops propagation.
```

arrowCheck function:

```
function arrowCheck(e) { e.stopPropagation(); }
```

This bit of code also works but ONLY AFTER the user has clicked the div once, the first time the div is clicked both functions fire off (ie the modal window and the extra buttons that the down arrow shows) but after the first click the addEventListener does it's job and clicking the down arrow only shows extra buttons, elsewhere brings up the modal, etc.

I'm guessing I need to create the event listener before the user clicks the div and fires off showModal(), is this correct? I'm not sure how to create a unique event listener for each down arrow image before the div is clicked, or even if I need to. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Since the event listener is being created within the modal function, you need to call the modal function before the other listener is even added.

To get your desired results, you could either directly add the onclick method to the image that the PHP code creates, or you could detect when the page is finished loading and add those listeners then. To do the latter, though, you'd need to either query for something the images all have in common, like a classname, or you'd have to keep track of the IDs used and manually add a listener for each. e.g.:

```
<body onload="initEventhandling()">

initEventHandling = function () {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("image-button");
    for (button in buttons) {
        button.addEventListener('click', arrowCheck, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

David Millar's code pointed me in the right direction. I tried to put the initEventHandling function in the onload of the body tag but I couldn't get it to work. It executed the function but I could not get the eventListeners to work. I solved it by creating an event listener using the onload for each img tag, so my code ended up like this:

```
<img id=\"".$appChart['ID']."_down-arrow\" onload=\"addEvent('".$appChart['ID']."')\" onclick=\"clickReviewArrow('".$appChart['ID']."')\" src='...' />
```

javascript:

```
function addEvent(ID) { var downArrow = document.getElementById(ID+'_down-arrow');
downArrow.addEventListener('click',arrowCheck,false); }

function arrowCheck(e) { e.stopPropagation(); }
```

David Millar may have been suggesting this, if so I'll mark his answer.